# Memcached Rails Cluster Configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memcached, cluster-computing

I have searched online but all the answers I have found were very primitive. Let's say I want to setup memchached in a Rails App on 3 different clusters. How do I go with configure this? What's the best way to do it? Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `config/environments/production.rb` set your cache store with multiple servers, like so:

```
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store,
                     "memcached1:11211",
                     "memcached2:11211",
                     "memcached3:11211"
```

This will setup a single cluster of memcache servers. If each is 1GB in size, then you'll have 3GB total of cache space.

See [Caching with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-memcachestore) for more info.

---

If instead you want to have access to 3 seperate memcache servers without integrating with Rails.cache, just create new `MemCache` connections. See [memcache-client's readme](https://github.com/mperham/memcache-client) for more info.